# Normal to a polyhedron in $n$ dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $P$ be a polyhedron in $n$ dimension such that $dim(P)<n$, then can I find a vector $c$ such that $c^Tx=k$ for some constant $k$ for all $x \in P$. I have seen that this is true for $n=2$. Is this true for any $n$? If yes how can I prove it?

Comment: Yes (I assume you want $c \neq 0$). This says exactly that if $\dim(P) < n$ then $P$ is contained in some affine hyperplane which is more or less true by definition. The set of vectors spanned by differences between points in $P$ spans a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $\dim(P) < n$ so there exists some nonzero vector orthogonal to all of them and that's your choice of $c$.

Comment: @Anton Vrdoljak Can you give a reference for $n=2$? As I see it, it is possible in the case $k=0$. If $k\neq 0$, I don't see how it is possible. Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, $P$ the segment $[0,1]$ along the $x$ axis, i.e. $P=\{ (x,0)^T | 0\leq x \leq 1 \}$. If one takes $c=(0,1)^T$, then $c^Tx=0$ for all $x\in P$. But if $k\neq 0$, $c$ should have an $x$ component and I don't see how $c^Tx$ can be a constant then.